# Creating reports in Access after the DB is completed

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

I have a fully functional DB developed in Access. It was done using a very "interactive" developer-client increment-iterative process as no one really knows what the final DB is to show. All tables were developed (and normalized) as well as forms (and sub-forms), however, now reports must be designed and implemented.

The forms of course, are based on queries which take the criteria from the form itself to run the queries and show information in the subforms. Now, as in practice, the reports have to basically be pretty printable versions of the on-screen forms for distribution. From my research, the reports are also based on queries, but since the queries I have are using the fields from the forms to display the relevant information in subforms, I don't see anyway to create these reports unless I basically duplicate all my queries to not pull values from forms. This seems very tedious and inefficient. Is this the "best practice" way to create reports for a database?

V.K.

Comment: Do you mean "subform" in the Access sense (i.e. a form that is embedded in another form) or do you mean just another form whose data depends on some filter critera entered in the first form? In the first case, you should not need form field references to link the form and its subform: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/subforms/link.php

Comment: I think part of your "incremental iteration" should have involved creating a report or two along the way. Report requirements should have been taken into consideration during the design of the database; if you did that, you wouldn't have painted yourself into this corner.

Comment: "a very "interactive" developer-client increment-iterative process" is how I've been doing things in Access for about 15 years now.  Ultra Frequent Application Deployment http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/ufad.htm

Comment: I don't have a choice as to how to carry out the life cycle. I was told, as a requirement that reports are to be done last, after all the forms are done.

It is subforms in the true access sense though, and the form/subfrom is linked by master/child fields for most of the forms.

Ultra Frequent Application Deployment - got to remeber that on! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can put a button on the form which launches the report using the same query. The report query will then use the fiels/query from the form, and should then return the same result set.

Comment: This could work only if all the information is on one form though, right? 

I have forms with subforms (and some with tabs) to display a set of related information which all are in different tables.

I would do this as an alternative to just printing (using the print button) reports for the short forms though.

Answer (score 2):

Hard-coding form fields in a query is the problematic part here -- that's definitely not "best practice". I guess you need these values in your WHERE clause? What you could do is to remove the field references from your queries (so that the query returns *all* records). In the Subform or Report, don't use the query directly as the record source. Instead, use some SQL that accesses your (generalized) query *and* and additional filter criteria. For example, the record source of your subform could be

```
SELECT * FROM myQuery WHERE someQueryField = Me.Parent!SomeFormField
```

allowing you to use the same `myQuery` with a different WHERE clause (which does not reference a Form) in your report.

Comment: If you are lucky, and there are any reports that can be populated using the hard-coded form references in the query, build those for now (If they are needed sooner than later.). For the other reports, I would use Heinzi's suggestion and rework those queries and forms.

Comment: I thought I shouldn't use SELECT * and just select only the fields I wanted because it would be inefficient pulling all the data for a record when I only want a known subset of the data.

I would try and rework the queries.

Comment: Well, if myQuery already contains only the fields you want (that was the impression I had, since you tailored the query specifically to the needs of one particular form), there's no point in repeating the same list of fields here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question, but having recently worked with an app that used a form to drive a report, I might have an inkling.

You don't *want* your report tied to the single record of the form. You *want* your report to use the same recordsource as the form, insofar as they are displaying the same data, of course.

The reason for this is that if you hardwire your report to the form fields, the report can't be used except when the form is open, and it can't display anything but one record.

If you create your report so it loads all records, then you'll need to be able to print one record at a time, and for that you just use the WHERE argument of the DoCmd.OpenReport command, using the PK value as your criterion.

So, yes, you should use the same recordsource. Why would anyone consider that a problem?